# Local and static variables in C

Tags: c, assembly, static

When compiling this:

```
// external definitions
int value1 = 0;
static int value2 = 0;
```

the gcc compiler generates the following assembly:

```
.globl value1
        .bss
        .align 4
        .type   value1, @object
        .size   value1, 4
value1:
        .zero   4
        .local  value2
        .comm   value2,4,4
```

However, when i initialize the variables to a value other than zero such as:

```
// external definitions
int value1 = 1;
static int value2 = 1;
```

the gcc compiler generated the following:

```
.globl value1
        .data
        .align 4
        .type   value1, @object
        .size   value1, 4
value1:
        .long   1
        .align 4
        .type   value2, @object
        .size   value2, 4
value2:
        .long   1
```

My questions are:

1. Why in the first case the values are allocated in the bss segment while in the second case in the data segment.
2. Why value2 variable is defined as .local and .comm in the first case, while not in the second.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your C code snippet but `value1` seems to be a global variable (rather than a local one). A local variable would be allocated on the stack.

Comment: Hard to say. I would consider putting that into `.bss` a bug. While there is no difference from the view of the standard (uninitialized variables should be initialized to `0`), it has become use that init'ing to `0` is distinct from being uninitialized.

Comment: @Codo both variable definitions in my snippets are external definitions and not locals.

Comment: @lefty: What do you mean by "external definition"? `value2` has _internal_ linkage.

Comment: @glglgl: Data in `.bss` *is* initialized.  It is initialized to zero.  Modern systems do not provide a way to create uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Codo I was not referring to their linkge. I mean that both variables are defined externally as opposed to internally to some function.

Comment: @CharlesBailey : I thinkd "external definition" mean global variable

Comment: @lefty: What you mean then is that they are defined at file scope.  (As opposed to block scope, function scope, etc.)  Internal / external are technical terms with specific definitions that means something else.

Comment: @DietrichEpp On embedded systems, there may be proprietary options to omit the `.bss`-zeroize-code. With "uninitialized" I mean "not explicitly initialized". By standard, `.bss` should indeed be init'ed to `0`, but some init code may provideways to alter this behaviour.

Comment: @glglgl: But it's wrong to say that putting zero-initialized data in `.bss` is a bug.  Sure, on some systems you can coerce the compiler to behave in non-standards-compliant ways, but that's not really relevant.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thx, wasn't aware of that. But [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) just taught me that "An implementation may also assign statically-allocated variables initialized with a value consisting solely of zero-valued bits to the bss section."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `bss` section contains uninitialized values and the `data` section contains initialized values. However, gcc places values that are initialized to zero into the `bss` section instead of the `data` section, as the `bss` section is zeroed out in runtime anyway, it doesn't make much sense to store zeros in the `data` section, this saves some disk space, from man gcc:

> -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss If the target supports a BSS section, **GCC by default puts variables that are initialized to zero into BSS.  This
>   can save space in the resulting code.** This option turns off this
>   behavior because some programs explicitly rely on variables going to
>   the data section

I'm not sure why `.comm` is used with *static* storage which is local to an object file, it is usually used to declare common symbols that, if *not* defined/initialized, should be merged by the linker with symbol that have the same name from other object files and that's why it's not used in the second example because the variables are initialized, from the `as` [manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Comm.html#Comm)

> .comm declares a common symbol named symbol. When linking, a common
>   symbol in one object file may be merged with a defined or common
>   symbol of the same name in another object file

Comment: Any ideas on the second part of my question?

Comment: @lefty: That's why it's not a good idea to ask two questions in one on Stack Overflow.  You can't choose two answers.

Comment: Saying that BSS contains uninitialized data is a little misleading since it is actually initialized at run time. Difference is mainly between whether it is done in program binary at compile time vs run time.

Comment: @fayyazkl I did say that it's initialized at runtime.

Comment: @mux I agree. Just emphasizing the initialization. I actually saw your initial answer, where i felt the run time initialization part wasn't mentioned. So i started writing one. Saw that latter once you edited.

Comment: This "putting zero-initialized data" into .bss by default must be something from newer versions of gcc. I've used `int magic_flag = 0;` in the past to force global variables into .data so that they can be binary patched after compilation.

Comment: @Art not sure which version introduced this, but that's why you probably shouldn't rely on that and use some compiler directive to store the data explicitly in the `.data` section

Comment: @mux It's an abuse of knowing exactly what the compiler does anyway. We could have initialized it to -1, but then nothing prevents the compiler or something else to create a .allbitsset section and put stuff in there. This is usually why things that do weirder things, like a kernel which it was in this case, are only supported with certain versions of certain compilers.

Answer (score 5):

The first case is because you initialized the values with zero.  It's part of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (section 6.7.8) that a global integer gets initialized with 0 if none is specified.  So file formats made a provision to keep binaries smaller by having a special section these get placed in: `bss`.  If you take a look at some of the [ELF specification](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf) (on page I-15), you'll find this:

> .bss This section holds uninitialized data that contribute to the program's 
>   memory image. By definition, the system initializes the data with zeros 
>   when the program begins to run. The section occupies no file space, as 
>   indicated by the section type, SHT_NOBITS.

In the first case, the compiler made an optimization.  It doesn't need to take up room in the actual binary to store the initializer, since it can use the `bss` segment and get the one you want for free.

Now, the fact that you have a static coming in from an external source is a bit interesting (it's not typically done).  In the module being compiled though, that should not be shared with other modules, and should be marked with `.local`.  I suspect it does it this way because there is no actual value to be stored for the initializer.

In the second example, because you've given a non-zero initializer, it know resides in the initialized data segment `data`.  `value1` looks very similar, but for `value2`, the compiler needs to reserve space for the initializer.  In this case, it doesn't need to be marked as `.local` because it can just lay down the value and be done with it.  It's not global because there is no `.globl` statement for it.

BTW, http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/ is a good place to visit for some of the low-level details about binary formats and such.

Answer (score 3):

[BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) is the segment containing data initialized at *run time* where as data segment contains data initialized in the *program binary*.

Now static variables are always initialized whether done explicitly in program or not. But there are two separate categories, initialized (DS) and uninitialized (BSS) statics.

All values present in BSS are those which are not initialized in the code of program and hence initialized when program is loaded at run time to 0 (if integer), null for pointers etc.

*So when you initialize with 0, the value goes to BSS where as any other value assigned will allocate the variable in Data segment.*

An interesting consequence is, *the size of data initialized in BSS will not be included in program binary, where as that of the one in data segment is included.*

Try allocating a large static array and use it in a program. See the executable size when it is not initialized explicitly in code. Then initialize it with non zero values like

```
static int arr[1000] = {2};
```

The size of executable in the latter case will be significantly greater