# Local and static variables in C (cont'd)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, static

Building on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580950/local-and-static-variables-in-c) i'm trying to figure out how `.local` and `.comm` directives work exactly and in particular how they affect linkage and duration in C.

So I've run the following experiment:

```
static int value;
```

which produces the following assembly code (using gcc):

```
.local  value
.comm   value,4,4
```

When initialized to zero yields the same assembly code (using gcc):

```
.local  value
.comm   value,4,4
```

This sounds logical because in both cases i would expect that the variable will be stored in the bss segment. Moreover, after investigating using `ld --verbose` it looks that all `.comm` variables are indeed placed in the bss segment:

```
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   // ...
  }
```

When i initialize however my variable to a value other than zero, the compiler defines the variable in the data segment as i would expected, but produces the following output:

```
        .data
        .align 4
        .type   value, @object
        .size   value, 4
value:
        .long   1
```

Besides the different segments (bss and data respectively) which thanks to your help previously i now understand, my variable has been defined as `.local` and `.comm` in the first example but not in the second. Could anyone explain that difference between the two outputs produced from each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.local` directive marks a symbol as a local, non-externally-visible symbol, and creates it if it doesn't already exist.  It's necessary for 0-initialized local symbols, because `.comm` declares but does not define symbols.  For the 1-initialized variant, the symbol itself (`value:`) declares the symbol.

Using `.local` and `.comm` is essentially a bit of a hack (or at least a shorthand); the alternative would be to place the symbol into `.bss` explicitly:

```
        .bss
        .align 4
        .type   value, @object
        .size   value, 4
value:
        .zero   4
```

Comment: `.comm` without `.local` would also work (the linker would define the symbol) but it would be globally visible and shared. By the way, `GAS` has `.lcomm` too.

Comment: @Jester `.comm` without `.local` doesn't make much sense in C (it might be useful in Fortran, though).  `.lcomm` isn't used here because it doesn't allow specifying alignment (on this platform).

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel zeros the virtual memory of a process after allocation due to security reasons. So, the compiler already knows that the memory will be filled with zeros and does an optimization: if some variable is initialized to 0, there's no need to keep space for it in a executable file (`.data` section actually takes some space in ELF executable, whereas `.bss` section stores only its length assuming that its initial contents will be zeros).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but my question was actually about the addition of .local and .comm directives in the first case but not the second.